# No response and no error returned from spring MVC for data size> 15 MB for a webservice API

Tags: json, web-services, java-8, tomcat8, spring-4

I am not able to get response or error for a request which is supposed to return data of size > 15 MB .My application is deployed on localhost on Apache tomcat 8 server.I am able to get response up to 15 MB successfully.

Customer don't want pagination for this so I am helpless now.
Even postman tool is not able to get return response anything.

I tried below things.

1.Setting Max post size in Apache tomcat server.xml
 and some other max size configurations.
2. Tried developers tool to know the error it says below error.

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>The requested URL could not be retrieved</title>
    <link href="http://passthrough.fw-notify.net/static/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://passthrough.fw-notify.net/static/default.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="checkResize();">
    <div id="emsg_large"></div>
    <div id="page">
      <div id="header">
        <div><img src="http://passthrough.fw-notify.net/static/topbar_left.png" width="6" height="72" border="0" /></div>
        <div id="company_logo"><img src="http://passthrough.fw-notify.net/static/logo.png" border="0" /></div>
        <div id="company_text"><h1 class="orange">UTM 9   http://www.sophos.com</h1></div>
        <div><img src="http://passthrough.fw-notify.net/static/topbar_right.png" width="6" height="72" border="0" /></div>
      </div>
      <br class="clearer" />

      <div id="content">
        <img src="http://passthrough.fw-notify.net/static/warning.png" border="0" align="left" />
        <h1 class="orange">An error occurred while handling your request</h1>

        <div class="line">
          <div class="label">While trying to retrieve the URL:</div>
          <div class="desc"> 
            <span></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="line">
          <div class="label">The content could not be delivered due to the following condition:</div>
          <div class="desc"> 
            Connection reset by peer
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="line">
          <div class="label">Your cache administrator is:</div>
          <div class="desc"> 
            sysad@mycomapny.com
          </div>
        </div>
        <br class="clearer" />
      </div> <!-- END: div#content -->
      <br class="clearer" />

      <div id="footer">
        <div><a href="http://www.sophos.com" target="_blank" title="Sophos"><img src="http://passthrough.fw-notify.net/static/footer_left.png" width="136" height="33" border="0" /></a></div>
        <div class="orange" id="copyright">Powered by UTM Web Protection</div>
        <div><img src="http://passthrough.fw-notify.net/static/footer_right.png" width="6" height="33" border="0" /></div>
      </div> <!-- END: div#footer -->
    </div> <!-- END: div#page -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this you connecting locally to localhost, or hosting on localhost but accessing remotely from another machine?

Comment: Looks like your Sophos UTM gateway is terminating the connection. You might need to adjust configuration in that tool.

Comment: thanks @NicholasSmith but I am have got this error when I tried to request API from local which deployed in some other environment. I have no clue that I am getting issue in my localhost as well but there is no error message I got for that